# Can I send email automatically from app

Tags: ios6, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, xcode4.6, mfmailcomposer

I am developing an app.

Can I know How to send  a email from app with out using email window.
ie, When I pressed a button I want to send mail automatically.

Without using the mail window.

[image]

Comment: FORTUNATELY, you can't send email automatically with iOS, without any explicit action from the user.

Comment: @Martin: I have a button Action. I need to send mail without using the mail composer window?

Comment: if your app can send an email with a button you implement, this app can *potentially* send the email in background. Apple force to open MFMailComposer because developers cannot control it and potentially abuse for spam purpose.
Nevertheless, you can still create a mailing webservice on your own server and call it with your app. Or use that "mailCore" lib, which won't work with the user preconfigured email accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MailCore framework, please take a look at this example: http://alwawee.com/wordpress/2012/06/25/how-to-build-mailcore-framework-on-ios/

> MailCore is a Cocoa e-mail framework built by Matt Ronge that is the
>   core of the e-mail client Kiwi. MailCore provides a nice set of
>   objects for working with IMAP, MIME and SMTP, all of which use the C
>   e-mail library LibEtPan.